# QueryEx and Query behavior

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I noticed a strange behavior when searching from IE and using the QueryEX/Query functions or the webservice.

I always get `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException` when I use the webservice to search.
But When I try the same search from website, I get valid results. Then if I go back and try the same search again using the webservice, I get valid results.

Nothing fancy here..

```
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query" Revision="1000">
    <Query domain="QDomain">
        <SupportedFormats>
            <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format>
        </SupportedFormats>
        <Range>
            <Count>50</Count>
        </Range>
        <Context>
            <QueryText language="en-US" type="STRING">"testtext" Site:"http://sps-internal.net/it/Dept/Public/"</QueryText>
        </Context>
    </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Comment: How are you calling the webservice? .NET code somewhere?

Comment: Adding `queryServiceSoapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;` solved the issue. I didn't quite understand why that is the case though.